# Were you aware of this behavior ? (PBI filterpane over slicer visual, sellect all/none selected issue)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hello I am trying to raise awareness about his subject I am facing this issue, I've posted on microsoft PBI community as wel, Did you even know about this, if so, how did you do to workaround this?

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Beware-Misleading-behaviour-using-Select-all-or-none-selected/m-p/1982650#M749494

As stated in the post, I have just found half a paragraph  hinting about this behaviour and all the people that I've talked to did not even know it behaved this way.

TL:DR. If you use the filter panel to filer a slicer (filter on this visual) in order to restrict the selection of a slicer (so your end user does not get lost in too many options or you want a dynamic slicer showing last x months, TOP N , basically any other advanced filtering optins given using this feature).
It only visually filters the slicer so if the user ends up using "select all" or even clearing the selection, all the data would be selected even the data you (as designer) wanted to filter out. Which is misleading since the end user would see the tag "all" over the slicer selection but when clicking on it it would only show the filtered out values, so they would naturally assume that "all" means just those values and not allvalues  (hidden values included).
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tHbC.png)
there are only two values to be selected in the slicer but the select all option actally seelcts all values including hidden ones

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check first, I bet you did not apply the filtered values in the filter pane on the whole page, rather you applied it only on the visual. Try to apply that on the whole page and it seems to work for me.

[image: Solution]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I did try that, as I described in the PBI forum link.
Doing that way it indeed kinda works, however what is hapenning is the behavior is still the same, when using select all/ none all values are selected, however since we are now filtering the whole page, all the charts will be filtered out by those same values.
In more complex models you have multiple filters on multiple slicers, if you apply them all to page filters there are times when you dont want it to filter a measure or a chart so you have to fix that in DAX and it becomes a mess to maintain.

Comment: In the above model, if I select all/ none, the measure will be sliced accordingly, e.g.2. So I disagree with you. Also I am not sure what are your expectations here. You want to apply a filter only on the visual level and yet you want the results of that filter to be applied to the page level? Can you create a use case and provide here? For more granular level controls use Edit Interactions